# Using AngularJS, how to make a cross-domain ajax request with basic authentication?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

New to AngularJS, and trying to hit a web service with basic auth using either $http or $resource. I haven't written any services or directives and basically just trying to do a call in my controller. Initially I prepended my url with the user/pw separated by an '@' symbol and I also have a callback that does a console out on the returned payload. Now I'm trying to change the $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'], but I feel like I should be using $resources. Any assistance on how to do basic auth with $resource (or $http) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$resources is a higher level abstraction that utilizes $http, so regardless of which one you choose to use, adding the Authorization header is a valid solution. Head over to the [angular $http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) for information on how to do that.

If you're doing anything more than hard coding a user/password into your application, you might want to take a look at response interceptors as a way to catch 401s and have your user log in. I've studied [this blog post](http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application) in the past when I was looking for a way to build fluid authentication into my app. I'd definitely recommend it if you're thinking about going down that path.